# HiKariCP for Bigquery

Tags: spring-boot, google-bigquery, hikaricp

I am new to gcloud and trying to leverage bigquery for accessing the data. I am trying to implement a connection pooling mechanism for bigquery and found that Hikari (one of the default datasource provided by spring boot) as a viable option. Could you please guide me in setting up the Bigquery credentials in the Hikari datasource as I am not able to figure out the way to give the driver, url and credentials.

I imported the bigquery api and hikari api in my pom dependencies

FYI: I am trying to make use of springboot

Comment: For Bigquery authentication you can take a look into [this document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication).

Comment: thank you. I think I found a way. I need to add JDBC drivers using Simba which is the official JDBC driver support for bigquery and then use that to develop a Hikari connection pool just using spring properties.

Comment: Great! If it worked to you, could you post it as an answer in order to help the community member who will have same problem =)

Comment: @enlelin : sorry for the delay, i initially thought that we found a way to use connection pooling using Hikari using Simba but was continuously facing errors. Hence we shifted to bigquery API. Also I tried CDATA jdbc drivers as well and seem to have connectivity issues while deploying to my app engine.

Comment: I understand that you are having connection issue to the datasource from Bigquery API. Can you show the error? (consider to update your post and provide more information)

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to establish connection from spring boot to bigquery using simba JDBC drivers and successfully queried it.

Firstly,  you need to include GCP starter dependency in your boot.

```
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
```

Dowload and add dependency jars of simba drivers in spring boot from the below link. Also refer installation guide in the link.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers

Secondly, create a service account that has access to bigquery and generate a key JSON file which is used to authenticate our spring boot application for connecting bigquery. Refer the below link.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication.

Lastly configure this key JSON file to be accessed by our spring book application using the simba driver JDBC installation guide.
Create a simba driver datasource and use this data source to create JDBC template bean. ( JDBC url formation is given in the installation guide of simba driver) . Thats it!! Run the application and see the results.

If you face any difficulties feel free to ask the specifics.

Comment: Thanks for the references provided. I have stopped working on the project. I will try these out later and let you know

Comment: When I started working the only thing I was able to find in stack overflow was your question but no answers... So after achieving it, I thought I will share my knowledge... I know it's  2 years late..but still... 

Comment: And I thank you for that actually :) Its alwalys a new learning for me  and I greatly appreciate it , you taking time to put this together and answer it :) . It will be useful for everyone who takes this route